# Querydsl InnerJoin DTO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpql, querydsl

I have something like that (myFavouriteBook and book are from querydsl QClasses):

```
JPAQuery<MyFavouriteBookDto> query = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager);

return query.select(Projections.bean(MyFavouriteBookDto.class,
            myFavouriteBook.customizationId,
            myFavouriteBook.position))
            .from(myFavouriteBook)
            .innerJoin(myFavouriteBook.book, book)
            .where(book.bookId.eq(myFavouriteBook.book.bookId))
            .fetch();
```

I don't want to get all fields from both classes, so I use dtos. But how can I use book dto instead of entity? 
I've tried to add

```
            myFavouriteBook.book
```

between

```
     myFavouriteBook.customizationId,
     myFavouriteBook.position
```

but there's an error that entity and dto are not compatible. I've tried with inner Projections.bean too, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate the fitting constructor of MyFavouriteBookDto as a `@QueryProjection`. This will generate `QMyFavouriteBookDto`. 
And then you need to use that generated class in `select` like `new QMyFavouriteBookDto(myFavouriteBook.customizationId, myFavouriteBook.position)` 
That should do the trick.